# MeshGeometry3D mesh to a Solid Surface or 3D Model? Using WPF and Helix toolkit

Tags: wpf, mesh, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using WPF and Helix toolkit to generate a Mesh.

*What I do in my code:*

First of all, I have a file that contains different profiles of a real object and the data are represented as X,Y,Z coordinates. So I start reading the data from the file:

```
MeshGeometry3D mesh;
for-loop
{
    --- File read function which returns X,Y,Z values ---
    // for each point add it to the mesh
    mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(temp_point.dX, temp_point.dY, temp_point.Z));
    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(indices++); // indices is just a counter from 0 to number of total points
}
modelGroup.Children.Add(new GeometryModel3D { Geometry = mesh, Material = material });
Model = modelGroup;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Model));
```

Then I get the points coordinates and add them to the mesh.

After the execution the result is the following:[image]

*Issue:*

If I start rotating the Model, the mesh sometimes is barely visible, and I know that is due to the triangles and the angle view.
Is there anyway to transform this mesh to a 3D model? or something that is more solid?
Can I use mesh.Positions or Mesh.TriangleIndices somehow to make the model solid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate triangle indices based on your data, so the mesh can be rendered properly. Currently you use vertex index as indices, which is not correct.

Comment: What I am doing is to connect consecutive vertices, for example: connect Vertex 0 with Vertex 1 and Vertex 2 with a triangle, and same thing for Vertex 3,4,5.
So what you tell me is that I  need to get all the Vertices and connect them with an algorithm in order to create a visible mesh?
There isn't a standard procedure for that kind of result that I need?

Comment: If I want to connect 3 Vertices with a Triangle, for example Vertex 5, vertex 10 and vertex 53, I should do mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(5), mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(10) and finally mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(53), these  3 lines of code with create the triangle. Am I correct or I have misunderstood the way the connections are being done.

Comment: It really depends on how your data set looks like in order to generate the correct triangles.

Comment: Yes of course, but the way I want to connect these 3 vertices:  Vertex 5, vertex 10 and vertex 53 I do it like mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(5), mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(10) and finally mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(53). This will create a 5,10,53 triangle?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **MeshBuilder** class. It has several methods yielding a valid MeshGeometry3D from 2-dimensional point arrays, without having to worry about triangle indexes.

The SurfacePlot example is a nice starting point for that,

https://helix-toolkit.github.io/demos/wpf/surfaceplot